# How to set default selected value in select control in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I have one form and i have put dropdownlistbox. Below is my code to populate dropdownboxlist with array.

```
<select class="with-icon"  ng-model="user.period" name="period" id="period" ng-options="user.ID as user.period for user in periodList" required>
                                                    <option value="" label="{{ 'Period' | translate }}">{{ 'Period' | translate }}</option>
                                                </select>
```

Below is my JS code.

```
 $scope.periodList = [{ ID: 1, period: '1 Month' }, { ID: 2, period: '2 Month' }, { ID: 3, period: '3 Month' }, { ID: 4, period: '4 Month' }, { ID: 5, period: '5 Month' }, { ID: 6, period: '6 Month' }];
```

I tried to set first value by default as below.

```
$scope.user.period =  [{ ID: 1, period:'1 Month' }];
```

This method did not work for me.
I tried below method   `$scope.user.period=1;` even this did not work for me. 
I tried  `$scope.user.period = $scope.periodList[1];` and this also dint work for me. Can someone help me to put up correct method to select first value by default. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working fine with `$scope.user.period =  1;` . maybe you forgot to declare the user as object first

```
 $scope.user = {};
 $scope.user.period =  1;
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 $scope.periodList = [{ ID: 1, period: '1 Month' }, { ID: 2, period: '2 Month' }, { ID: 3, period: '3 Month' }, { ID: 4, period: '4 Month' }, { ID: 5, period: '5 Month' }, { ID: 6, period: '6 Month' }];
$scope.user = {};
$scope.user.period =  1;

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <select class="with-icon"  ng-model="user.period" name="period" id="period" ng-options="user.ID as user.period for user in periodList" required>
                                                    <option value="" label="{{ 'Period' }}">{{ 'Period'  }}</option>
                                                </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem was  $scope.user = {};
 $scope.user.period =  1;$scope.user = {};. I had at the end again $scope.user = {};

Comment: remove that. it will remove the values

Answer (score 1):

Try to set it like this:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {};
 $scope.periodList = [{ ID: 1, period: '1 Month' }, { ID: 2, period: '2 Month' }, { ID: 3, period: '3 Month' }, { ID: 4, period: '4 Month' }, { ID: 5, period: '5 Month' }, { ID: 6, period: '6 Month' }];
 $scope.user.period = $scope.periodList[0].ID;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select class="with-icon"  ng-model="user.period" name="period" id="period" ng-options="user.ID as user.period for user in periodList" required>
<option value="" label="{{ 'Period'}}">{{ 'Period'}}</option>
</select>
{{user.period}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
<select ng-init="somethingHere = periodList[0]"> ... </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs, you need to assign the `ng-model` to be the item in the list used to create your options that you want to be pre-selected. In this case, the first item in `$scope.periodList`.

```
<select class="with-icon"  ng-model="periodList[0]" name="period" id="period" ng-options="user.ID as user.period for user in periodList" required>
   <option value="" label="{{ 'Period' | translate }}">{{ 'Period' | translate }}</option>
</select>
```

You can find more info here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions